# How to ignore hashrouter?

Tags: react-router

I have a simple hashrouter set up but when i press the button for my dropdown the content disapears, Is there a workaround ?

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <fragment>
        <HashRouter>
          <Navbar className="header">

            <NavLink to="/Shop"> <NavItem icon={<IoIosBasket />}  /> </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/Home"> <NavItem icon={<IoIosHome />} /> </NavLink>

            <NavItem icon={<IoIosListBox />} />
            <NavItem icon={<IoIosArrowDown />}>

              <DropdownMenu></DropdownMenu>
            </NavItem>
          </Navbar> 
          <div className="content">
            <Route path="/Home" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/Shop" component={Shop}/>  
            // Test text
          </div>
        </HashRouter>  
      </fragment>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in console

Comment: none, i would just like to know how i can ignore some buttons